# Ef core Creating additional column for a navigation property with Name *ID1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm using Ef core Code First to generate a Database. But I'm not sure why it's creating a new column with *ID1.

**Entity**

```
public class Room : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public CommonStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
public class RoomConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Room>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Room> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(10);
        builder.Property(t => t.UniqueCode).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(10);
        builder.HasIndex(p => p.Status);
        builder.HasOne(s => s.Branch)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BranchId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

**Migration**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Room",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
                    UniqueCode = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
                    BranchId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Status = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    BranchId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
                }
```

As You can sett the migration script actually has BranchId1 which I never defined. and this happening in some entity as well but not all. I just want to know why it's happening thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified the navigation property on `.WithMany()`.

WithMany():

> Configures this as a one-to-many relationship. Note that calling this method with no parameters will explicitly configure this side of the relationship to use no navigation property, even if such a property exists on the entity type. **If the navigation property is to be used, then it must be specified.**

What happens is EF first configures your relation that you made with the fluent API, then it also creates a relation for `List<Rooms>`. Since `BranchId` is already used for your fluent relationship it creates a second FK called `BranchId1`.

So your relation should be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Room>().HasOne(s => s.Branch)
    .WithMany(x => x.Rooms)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.BranchId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```